# Skaction followed by scene transition

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to make a node perform an action followed by a scene transition once the button is touched.

Here's what I have so far:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    var touch = touches as!  Set<UITouch>
    var location = touch.first!.locationInNode(self)
    var node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
    var action = SKAction.moveToY(PlayButton.position.y + self.size.height, duration: 5)

    // If next button is touched, start transition to second scene
    if (node.name == "Balloon") {
        PlayButton.runAction(action)
        var secondScene = Scene2(size: self.size)
        var transition = SKTransition.flipVerticalWithDuration(1.0)
        secondScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
        self.scene!.view?.presentScene(secondScene, transition: transition)}


}
```

Once I click on the button using the simulator the scene transitions without performing the action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a sequence action together with a block action. Create a block action to deal with the scene-transition, something like this:

```
if (node.name == "Balloon") {
        let sceneAction = SKAction.runBlock({
            let secondScene = Scene2(size: self.size)
            let transition = SKTransition.flipVerticalWithDuration(1.0)
            secondScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
            self.scene!.view?.presentScene(secondScene, transition: transition)}
        })
        playButton.runAction(SKAction.sequence([action, sceneAction]))
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great